# How to add a Textbox to Dynamic GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I add Textbox to a dynamic Gridview. Do I need to have a customised Templete Field ? Is there any other way ??

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to dynamically generate rows with TextBoxes in a GridView?  If so, then there is a good explanation here:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/04/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textboxes.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200811153253/http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/04/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textboxes.aspx)

Here's one if you're just looking to add a control to a single cell.  It's a DropDownList, but could be modified to add a TextBox:

[http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/708.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628005021/http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/708.html)

Comment: Hi, My gridview is being build dynamically at runtime. Here I need a textbox in each row of a column.